# Not sure if my use of mathematical notation is even correct

Tags: support

I just [asked a question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4424424/453069) on this site. One thing I've noticed looking at other questions is that most seem to have pretty good formal questions and good use of accurate mathematical notation. Creating maths questions is not a skill I was taught at School or University, so I rarely know if I have enough info in the question, if I have written it correctly or if I have some ambiguity there. It's very hard to be precise about the question when I don't already know the answer. Is there some way to mark my question as "open to be edited to fix incorrect notation"?

Comment: No need – it's assumed that every question is open to editing by users who have accumulated enough points.

Comment: You might try asking for specific notation advice in the [Constructive Feedback](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43593/constructive-feedback) chatroom.  Also you can view the edit history of related posts to see how others have improved their notation.

Comment: @hardmath, Can low-reputation users view edit histories?

Comment: @GEdgar:  The Help Center's page on [https://math.stackexchange.com/help/editing](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/editing) describes it as "public revision history" and says one can view it by "clicking the date and time next to the edited post."  Although 2,000 reputation is needed to make an edit that bypasses going through the Suggested Edit queue, my reading is that one doesn't even need to be logged in to see the revision history.  I will test my interpretation (if I can remember how to log out).

Comment: Figuring out how to log out was [somewhat interesting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23102/logging-out-of-stack-overflow-or-any-stack-exchange-site) given the changes in UI over the years, but I managed it.  Verified that being logged out still allows me to view the edit history on any post where the "edited yesterday" or similar link appears to the left (or above, on "responsive" mobile layout) of the original poster notice (below the post but above all Comments on it).

Comment: @hardmath  Thanks for checking that.